# Get specific fields from a formset

Tags: django, django-templates

For the documentation, I'm able to display a formset as below

```
<table>
    {{ formset }}
</table>
```

However, what if I want to format the layout manually?  Like how it's done for ModelForms?  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{% for form in formset %}
   {% for field in form %}
       do something with {{ field }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Just went through the docs again...almost beat myself when it finally hit me...got the same solution as you Daniel so thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can do form.field name, `Example: {{ form.username }}`, [django-display form template](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#s-displaying-a-form-using-a-template)

Answer (score 1):

I do something like this.

```
{{ form.username.errors }}
<label for="id_username">Username:</label>
{{ form.username }}<br />

{{ form.password.errors }}
<label for="id_password">Password:</label>
{{ form.password }}
```

Or you could do if you didn't need to customize the label element

```
{{ field.username_tag }}: {{ form.username}}
```